# TemplateBinding ReadOnly from DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="OrderItemList" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price`}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Qty}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                 BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="...." />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I bind the DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly to TextBox.IsReadOnly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridCell` has a property called `Column` which returns the column the cell belongs to.

Try something like `IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Column.IsReadOnly, Mode=OnTime}"`